# How to format a variable in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am trying to grab the formatted current data and create a variable from it using the command:

`gen %tdCY-N-D final_dayinpt = date(c(current_date), "DMY")`

However, I am getting an error

```
%tdCY invalid name
r(198);
```

If I display this at the Stata command line it works:

```
. display  %tdCY-N-D date(c(current_date), "DMY")
2020-10-27
```

How can I create this formatted variable?

Comment: It may not be the most concise solution, but if you generate the date variable in one command, then in the next command type `format final_dayinpt %tdCY-N-D`, that should work.

Comment: Also specifying the format after `gen` and before `newvar` doesn't seem like legal Stata syntax. See `help generate`.

Comment: @Cybernike is correct. The format can't be part of the `generate` command, as the syntax diagram in its help shows.

Comment: @Cybernike, I would accept your answer if there were one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
set obs 10 // so the example works
generate final_dayinpt = date(c(current_date), "DMY")
format final_dayinpt %tdCY-N-D
```

The syntax you're trying is tempting because the format you use for `display` is *seems* analogous to things like `generate byte bytevar = 1`, but, as you found the analogy doesn't hold here.

Note that you are passing format information where `type` is expected based on the `generate` syntax (`help generate`):

```
generate [type] newvar[:lblname] =exp [if] [in] [, before(varname) | after(varname)]
```

While consulting `help generate` and `help display` are helpful, `help datetime` is also very useful here (and was never obvious to me).

[See here for a more thorough treatment of working with dates in Stata.](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/stata_dates.htm)

### Edit:

An alternative suggested (and made possible by) Nick Cox:

```
ssc install numdate // install the package which Nick wrote
generate current_date = c(current_date) // numdate takes a varlist
numdate daily final_dayinpt = current_date, pattern(DMY) format(%tdCY-N-D)
```

Comment: This answer combines the comments from Cybernike and Nick Cox. Note that `generate` does not allow a single step solution.

Comment: That account is helpful but the full story is at -help datetime-.

Comment: You can specify the format in the `numdate` command from SSC. As you want a non-default format any way, you have to spell it out somewhere, and Arthur's method is fine.

Comment: Good point, great package. I've added it to the answer.